# How can I get diff between two git commits in a human-readable format?

Tags: xcode, git, diff

I tried

```
git diff foo1 foo2 > diff.txt
```

but it seems too hard to read, especially when foo1 and foo2 have lots of commits between them. Is there any way I could get the difference between the commits in a human readable format, like one would see in an Xcode commit?

Comment: Why is the output of that command _too hard to read_, and how could it be more "human readable"?

Answer (score 0):

git diff is as human readable as it gets... but a graphical diff tool is probably what you are looking for.

As this question is tagged Xcode, you can view differences in Xcode with the appropriate view (per file), or use a full blown git client, for example [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you output to a diff file (.diff not .txt) you will probably get colour-coding, which makes it easier to read.

For graphical comparison of files there are many tools. I like Beyond Compare, but there are loads of others.

Answer (score 0):

If for you is not enough SourceTree, I would recommend you [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com), this allows you compare huge folder structures, althoug is not a free tool, it pays the price.